# Python Selenium trying to click button not working

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, bots, browser-automation

I'm trying to click in a button by using CSS Selector. I've tried by using *input with value, title and onclick* but not working, this is **html code**:

```
<div id="botaoMarcar"><input type="button" disabled class="botao"
value="Marcar todas" title="Marcar todas" onclick="javascript:marcarDesmarcarTodos(true);"
></div>
```

**My code:**

```
driver = Chrome()
url = "https://www3.bcb.gov.br/sgspub/localizarseries/localizarSeries.do?method=prepararTelaLocalizarSeries"
driver.get(url)

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),
                                   'Timed out waiting for PA creation ' + 'confirmation popup to appear.')

    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
except TimeoutException:
    print("No Alert")


driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.maximize_window()

# This part is for input table code that I want to access
id_code = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'txCodigo')
id_code.send_keys(24)
id_code.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# Part not working exactly
clic_code = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[value*="Marcar todas"]')
clic_code.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just went another way and implemented the function to mark all didn't seem like the element was in an iframe.

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("marcarDesmarcarTodos(true);")
```

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: So after this, how can I 'click' in the box?